# Routing error: undefined method `add_breadcrumb' for Controller:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, breadcrumbs

I am trying to implement the [breadcumbs on rails](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails) plugin but am getting some errors.

Gemfile is set

```
gem 'breadcrumbs_on_rails'
```

In my controller "DealsController"

```
class DealsController < ApplicationController    
    add_breadcrumb "home", :root_path
    add_breadcrumb "deals", :deals_path
```

In the index action

```
add_breadcrumb "index", index_path
```

However when I load the deals index view I get this routing error

```
undefined method `add_breadcrumb' for DealsController:Class
```

I haven't touched the routes file, just followed instructions from github. Kind of new at this. Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used breadcrumb before, have you bundle install?

Comment: yes that was run. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hm, for me it does work.

1. add gem to Gemfile
2. run bundle
3. somehow create Rails resource (route +
   controller + action + view) for example with

   rails g scaffold products name:string
4. set root route in routes.rb

   root to: 'products#index'
5. add render_breadcrumbs to application layout

That works for me. But only the top level statements. Don't understand yet, why add_breadcrumb in controller action does not seem to work for me.